# Make single method call without class from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, bluej

In eclipse, how would I go about making a method call without writing a test class. For example, if I'm making a method that performs a certain algorithm, is it possible for me to simply call the method and pass the parameters in? I know the BlueJ IDE can do this so I'm sure Eclipse can, I'm just not sure how.

Thanks!

Comment: Creating a test class is the only way you can do it in eclipse as far as I know...I too have searched for a long time...couldn't find any other alternative.

Comment: @NiranjanRavichandran I'm surprised Eclipse doesn't support this feature. I feel that even though it is easily done by making a test class, it still can make it easier to develop if you only need to test your algorithm once. Sadly though, the closest thing that Eclipse has is the Scrapbook file so I guess I'll just work with a test class.

Comment: @Globmont: most test cases I've run into deal with testing a class, and not a single method. I've seen what BlueJ can do, and I've seen what Eclipse can do, and I'll never give up my Eclipse for BlueJ. I'm just too addicted to its shear power.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Oh, absolutely! BlueJ is nowhere near as good as Eclipse. Even though I test classes most of the time, there are those occasions where testing a single algorithm without having to write multiple lines of code would come in handy. Oh well. I guess it isn't a feature that get's requested often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `main(String[] args)` method to run anything in Java, and it needs to be in a class. Solution: create your test class. Welcome to real Java.

Comment: I'm aware that I can make a test class with a main method. But I assume since such a basic IDE as BlueJ (which is basically a glorified text editor) has the feature, something so fancy as Eclipse should. I'm just looking for a quick way to test a method once without having to make a test class, instantiate the class, and make a method call.

Comment: @Globmont: BlueJ has certain strengths as does Eclipse. I'm guessing this is one strength that BlueJ has that Eclipse does not.

Comment: I guess so. Oh well, I guess I'll just settle for a test class.